Not getting Passport session on production, but the same code works fine in local host
i am using passportjs for google authentication it is working fine in localhost but when i host it on render it is not returning the session, it only returns the empty cookie on the production but in the local environment it also returns a passport object inside of the session and the passport object contains the user information stored in the database
//server.js

import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as oAuth2Strategy } from "passport-google-oauth2";
import "./db/connect.js";
import { userdb } from "./model/user.js";
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE",
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "Content-Type",
    "Accept",
    "Authorization",
    "token",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
  ],
  credentials: true,
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.set("trust proxy", 1); // trust first proxy
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI,
      ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Session TTL (optional)
      autoRemove: "native", // Automatically remove expired sessions (optional)
    }),
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
  new oAuth2Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL:
        "https://appname/auth/google/callback",
      scope: ["profile", "email"],
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await userdb.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value });
        console.log(user);
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          const user = new userdb({
            name: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            picture: profile.photos[0].value,
          });
          await user.save();
          return done(null, user);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error, null);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: process.env.BASE_URL,
    failureRedirect: process.env.BASE_URL + "/login",
  })
);

app.get("/login/success", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.session) {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "user Login", session: req.session });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Not authenticated" });
  }
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    req.session.destroy();
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect(process.env.BASE_URL);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

// frontend running on localhost:3000

const GoogleLogin = () => {
  const loginwithgoogle = () => {
    window.open(
      "https://appname/auth/google/callback",
      "_self"
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-[100vh]">
      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        type="button"
        onClick={loginwithgoogle}
      >
        Sign in With google
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoogleLogin;

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ServiceData = () => {
  const [serviceData, setServiceData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [session, setSession] = useState({});

  console.log(session); // This logs the session object

  // Function to fetch user data
  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://appname/login/success",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      setSession(response.data.session);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  };

  // Function to log out
  const logout = () => {
    window.open("https://appname/logout", "_self");
  };

  // Fetch service data
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://appname/api/getServiceData",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      setServiceData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  // Fetch user data when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-[100vh]">
      {session.passport && session.passport.user ? (
        <>
          <span>{session.passport.user.name}</span> {/* Accessing user name */}
          <span>{session.passport.user.email}</span>
          <img src={session.passport.user.picture} alt="" />
          <button
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={fetchData}
            disabled={isLoading}
          >
            {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Get Service Data"}
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={logout}
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
          >
            Logout
          </button>
          <div className="max-h-[300px] overflow-y-auto border border-solid border-[#ccc] p-3 mt-5">
            {serviceData.length > 0 && (
              <ul>
                {serviceData.map((service, index) => (
                  <li key={index}>
                    <strong>Code:</strong> {service.code},{" "}
                    <strong>Name:</strong> {service.name},{" "}
                    <strong>Price:</strong> {service.price}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            )}
            {serviceData.length === 0 && !isLoading && (
              <p>No service data available.</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>Hello</>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServiceData;



who can i solve this issue ?
